# Heroku and Chaining Nested HTTP Requests (Alamofire/NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, heroku, alamofire

I am attempting to nest two get requests inside of each other

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "serverAddress")
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                //populate parameters with the expected args
                var parameters:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()
                //Request2
                self.queryFriendsList(parameters)
        }
```

Here is the nested request within a different method...

```
func queryFriendsList(parameters:[String:[String]]) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "serverAddress", parameters : parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            if let res = response.result.value {
                print(res)
            }
    }
}
```

When I check my logs on Heroku I see:

```
heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/query_friends_list/"
```

The log associated with the app reports:

```
Error: request aborted
at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/app/node_modules/raw-    body/index.js:269:10)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:281:11)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:294:5)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

The second request is dependent upon the first succeeding.
I am at a loss as to how to debug this one. I am using the free version of Heroku, so I wasn't able to determine from the docs if multiple requests would be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this bug had to do with me not understanding where to look for the error...

```
sock=client
```

Denoted that the issue was associated with the client side. Initially I had specified a get request for my http request to heroku. I specified parameters to be encoded with JSON but I realized I cannot send a payload encoded with JSON on a get request.

This was really the root issue at hand. After switching my route to a post request and updating the calls in my swift project, I was able to make the proper query against my DB!